# The name 'angular' does not exist in the current context - angular 2, using material design css

Tags: angular

I'm trying to include some default themes in my angular 2 application (in visual studio 2015).

I've added the following css line in my header, as it's done in the [demo app](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/demo-app/index.html):

```
<link href="@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But I'm getting the error `The name 'angular' does not exist in the current context`.

I also found [this guide](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/docs/theming.md). However, I can't seem to get any of the steps to work. I presume the "@angular" isn't working because I'm not using the "CLI". However, I can't get any form of direct reference working either.

I can find the css file in my `D:\Projects\ProjectName\ProjectName\node_modules\@angular\material\core\theming` folder fine, but I can't find any way to reference it.

This produces the same error as above:

```
<link href="./node_modules/@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Is there some issue with the '@' in the filename? I might be making a really obvious error, as this is my first proper web application.

Comment: I am guessing that the build pipeline is not serving `node_modules`. In your browser type the whole url e.g. `localhost:9000/node_modules/@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/indigo-pink.css` and test it.

Comment: http://localhost:49954/node_modules/@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/indigo-pink.css gives a 404

Comment: Make sure your server is serving from additional root. You can post how you are serving your app (e.g. gulp serve or webpack or grunt) to help.

Comment: Those keywords helped me find what I'm looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35527667/1305699. I think to keep it simple I'll just copy over files I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have  RAZOR View Engine parsing exception ?

'@' - razor server side system symbol ,

if you want used this symbol on src link - declare on view: 
@{ var @angular = "@angular"; }

Answer (score 0):

Could you add node_modules/ prior to @angular?

this is also descriped in https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/docs/theming.md

another option is to add to styleUrls in your component:
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'my-template.html',
    styleUrls: ['node_modules/@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/indigo-pink.css']
})