# Failed to load resource?

Tags: asp.net, node.js, angular

I have a ASP.NET Core 1.1 where I have followed this guide :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HB6ftmxKzL8

I do however not get the Angular Module to run, its just stating "Loading". I can see in the webdev tool that some resources could not load(404)

http://localhost:44343/System.config.js
http://localhost:44343/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.js
http://localhost:44343/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js
http://localhost:44343/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js
http://localhost:44343/System.config.js
http://localhost:44343/

To activate Facebook login I hade to activate SSL but this is switched off again. This is how my Startup.Configure looks like :

```html
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseIdentity();

            // Add external authentication middleware below. To configure them please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715

            //https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/facebook-logins
            app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookOptions()
            {
                AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"],
                AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"]
            });

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

The files do exists but they is placed under node_modules instead of under the wwwroot? In another video about ASP.NET Core it was said that all static that is publiched need to be placed under the wwwwroot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by custom serve the app and node_modules as descibed in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39465629/365624

I also hade to move the system.config.js to the root of wwwroot.

Im not sure if this is the right way to handle it and I suspect that I will have to package the custom server files at deployment in some way.